# What's new in Hamcrest 1.2?

Tags: testing, hamcrest

What's the difference between Hamcrest 1.1 and 1.2? I couldn't find a release notes page or a file listing changes! Where can I find such info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution contains a `CHANGES.txt` file.  Not sure how complete it is, though.

Comment: Thank you. The file is not included in the "hamcrest-all.jar" file that I downloaded, but I could now find it in the "hamcrest-1.2.zip"  download.